# git library for Go

Tags: git, go

As a pet project, I want to develop a note taking app using git as storage backend. (I suspect this doesn't exist yet, given this guy's blog post: http://jarofgreen.co.uk/2012/08/how-about-a-mobile-note-app-backed-by-git/ )

Now, I'd like to take this as an opportunity to play around with Go a bit. However, I cannot seem to find any (not even the tiniest approach to) git library for Go.
Is there actually any?

Obviously my knowledge of Go is non-existant, so writing bindings for libgit doesn't seem a fun way to start... (and I would probably resort to ruby, which I don't know either)

Comment: I was sure to have seen a similar question some time ago but I can't find it. Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I'd say [git2go](https://github.com/libgit2/git2go) is the git bindings library to use in Go. It is updated regularly and maintained by the people running libgit2.

If you are looking for a git implementation purely written in Go, [go-git](https://github.com/go-git/go-git) the most mature and active option.

Comment: This package is relatively new (compared to question). This is currently the best choice. (Should be marked as correct answer for future reference.)

Comment: I ended up going with go-git, git2go is a huge hassle to get working properly on a Windows machine.

Comment: I say https://github.com/go-git/go-git looks good.

Answer (score 16):

Since a few years ago, my team and I, we were coding a pure git implementation in Go, it avoids to have any c/c++ dependency and make it more flexible and easy to extend.

https://github.com/go-git/go-git

> go-git aims to reach the completeness of libgit2 or jgit, nowadays covers the majority of the plumbing read operations and some of the main write operations, but lacks the main porcelain operations such as merges.

Answer (score 15):

You can just shell out to `git` command using [os/exec](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/) package from Go standard library.

Comment: That is [what the official 'go' command does](https://golang.org/src/cmd/go/vcs.go).

Comment: Updated link: https://golang.org/src/cmd/go/internal/get/vcs.go

Comment: Updated updated link: https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17:src/cmd/go/internal/vcs/vcs.go;l=152

Answer (score 7):

What Victor proposed is indeed the "official" way to "script" Git as envisioned by its developers.  Git's commands are divided in the two broad groups specifically for this purpose: the "plumbing" commands are low-level and inteneded mostly to be used by other programs; the "porcelain" command are intended to interact with the user, and call plumbing commands to do their work.  Look inside the `/usr/lib/git-core` directory (might be different on your system) to get the idea of how many plumbing commands Git has.

On the other hand, Go supports linking with shared libraries via its [`cgo`](http://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) facility.  You hence could try wrapping [`libgit2`](http://libgit2.github.com/) with it.  AFAIK, `libgit2` is not yet fully on par with the Git itself, but it is able to read/write Git repositories, do branching etc — supposedly it will be enough for your task.

Okay, after I wrote all that, I scrolled down the "Bindings" entry on the `libgit2`'s site and found [`go-git`](https://github.com/str1ngs/go-git)...

Comment: Ok, fair enough. I think I'll still resort to some form of bindings (go-git seems quite interesting), that just seems an easier way to deal with the commands output...

Answer (score 3):

A [search for "git" on GoDoc](http://godoc.org/?q=git) turns up some projects. There's a libgit2 wrapper, and at the bottom is [an unfinished Git implementation in Go](https://github.com/edsrzf/go-git).

Comment: Oh, thanks, I didn't even know about GoPkgDoc in the first place

Answer (score 2):

The [golang-gitoperations](https://github.com/amzn/golang-gitoperations) module provides an os/exec based interface to the command line tool.

Answer (score 0):

> use git as storage backend

Then the Go library [**`fluxcd/go-git-providers`**](https://github.com/fluxcd/go-git-providers) can come in handy.

> `go-git-providers` is a general-purpose Go client for interacting with Git providers' APIs (e.g. GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket).

Example:

```golang
package github_test

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/fluxcd/go-git-providers/github"
    "github.com/fluxcd/go-git-providers/gitprovider"
    gogithub "github.com/google/go-github/v32/github"
)

func ExampleOrgRepositoriesClient_Get() {
    // Create a new client
    ctx := context.Background()
    c, err := github.NewClient()
    checkErr(err)

    // Parse the URL into an OrgRepositoryRef
    ref, err := gitprovider.ParseOrgRepositoryURL("https://github.com/fluxcd/flux")
    checkErr(err)

    // Get public information about the flux repository.
    repo, err := c.OrgRepositories().Get(ctx, *ref)
    checkErr(err)

    // Use .Get() to aquire a high-level gitprovider.OrganizationInfo struct
    repoInfo := repo.Get()
    // Cast the internal object to a *gogithub.Repository to access custom data
    internalRepo := repo.APIObject().(*gogithub.Repository)

    fmt.Printf("Description: %s. Homepage: %s", *repoInfo.Description, internalRepo.GetHomepage())
    // Output: Description: The GitOps Kubernetes operator. Homepage: https://docs.fluxcd.io
}
```