# GO-Github API: How To Commit and Push to a remote branch

Tags: go

I'm trying to use [Go-Github](https://github.com/google/go-github) to create a text file and push it into a remote branch but I'm totally confused on how to do it.

I'm able to get a listing of repositories with my client org

```
repos, _, err := client.Repositories.ListByOrg("MyOrg", nil)
```

I'm able to use that and get a remote branch

```
branch, resp, err := client.Repositories.GetBranch("MyOrg", "MyRepository", "MyBranch")
```

but for the life of me I'm unable to figure out how to commit a file (or files) in my local branch and push the commit to the remote branch.

Thanks for any help that anyone can give.

Comment: You don't, you use git for that. The GitHub API has nothing to do with your local repositories.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a different library to (in your local repo):

- add a remote referencing your GitHub repo
- fetch the remote branches
- push your own branch.

See "[git library for Go](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13532389/6309)", like the [**libgit2/git2go**](https://github.com/libgit2/git2go) project (and [its push test](https://github.com/libgit2/git2go/blob/41008af54cfc2af3a5ea56dff169c95d2b50dda6/push_test.go#L37-L44)).

```
push, err := remote.NewPush()
checkFatal(t, err)
err = push.AddRefspec("refs/heads/master")
checkFatal(t, err)
err = push.Finish()
checkFatal(t, err)
```